# show create table in hive using java

Tags: java, hadoop, jdbc, hive

I am trying to execute show create table  statement thru a JDBC hive connection. The aim is to get the location of the file containing the data of hive table.

I tried the following code but got following exception:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(hiveTable);

    System.out.println("Resultset not null"+(rs != null));
    int i = 0;
    while(rs.next()){
        System.out.println(rs.getString(i));
        i++;
}
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:4 cannot recognize input near 'show' '<EOF>' '<EOF>' in ddl statement
        at org.apache.hive.jdbc.Utils.verifySuccess(Utils.java:120)
        at org.apache.hive.jdbc.Utils.verifySuccessWithInfo(Utils.java:108)
        at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.execute(HiveStatement.java:233)
        at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.executeQuery(HiveStatement.java:376)
        at com.capitalone.def.impl.TestClass.main(TestClass.java:33)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
```

Please help me resolve this.

Comment: What does "hiveTable" contain ?

Comment: show create table <tableName>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using following code you can get table location

```
HiveConf conf = new HiveConf();
conf.set(HiveConf.ConfVars.METASTOREURIS.varname, <metaStoreURI>);
HiveMetaStoreClient hiveMetaStoreClient = new HiveMetaStoreClient(conf);
Table tab = hiveMetaStoreClient.getTable(<db name>, <tab name>);
tab.getSd().getLocation()
```